# Lightning Add Products standard button

Tags: lightning-aura-components

So when you click the add products standard button on an opportunity page it directs you to the following page [image: o]

so i'm looking at the chrome dev console, and i'm wondering....can i pass a parameter into the search products section via a url button (lightning:isUrlAddressable)? OR alternatively can i embed this function in another lightning component to then pass a parameter to it? Or do i have to just remake the whole damn thing i can pass a parameter to that single search bar? The business simply wants a button to click where you click it and only X products show up, and i found out if you just type in X (a variable) into the search it just shows the products. which is why i was wondering if it's possible to pass params to that.